# Linux I2C custom message frame sending

Tags: embedded-linux, i2c

Is it possible to send out a custom message frame on I2C dev from Linux? I am using an i.MX7D board and i would like to use "/dev/i2c-0" device like a simple "serial tty" to "write(fd, bytes, count)". My goal is to send out a single byte for example 0xAB on I2C without any specific slave address and without automatic stop/start bit inserting in my frame.

So i like to make my full custom I2C frame then send it out from Linux. Is it possible, is there any user-space programing techniques in C/C++, Python or any API for it in Linux?

Comment: If you use /dev/i2c, you only get what it provides, which is i2c protocol: https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v3.19.8/source/Documentation/i2c/dev-interface

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**No you can't**, because this is limited by the hardware, if you are using the I2c interface, the hardware will limit what you can do.

One way to try is that you can use **gpio** to simulate i2c or any interface you want to. Many chips support setting the i2c interface to gpio, then you simulate a clock with one gpio, and simulate high and low level with another gpio.

**But I don't recommend it**, because if you don't follow the i2c protocol, you can't communicate with other i2c devices

Comment: *Some* hardware devices can't. Others may be multiplexed with GPIO. But yeah, *if you're using hardware in I2C mode* then it's going to speak I2C language.

Comment: I would like to communicate with a non-consumer I2C device, it is requre a single byte message to wake up it in normal I2C communication mode. After this magic service data message in I2C communication line this device can operate well in the normal I2C protocol. By the way, there must be no any other devices in the bus, otherwise it can not operate well.

Comment: As i see in Linux I2C driver it is limited only in the standard Linux driver. It seems to me I2C driver of NXP i.MX can transfer any custom byte or frame just the implementation is not yet ready for it.

https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v5.18.10/source/drivers/i2c/busses/i2c-imx.c#L1104

Comment: @Livius, i2c protocol limits message size and sequence of ACK/NACK/RESTART/etc.

Comment: I don't see how you can control the hardware not to send start\end or ack, in fact it needs to check the hardware manual to confirm.

Answer (score 0):

Connect two GPIO lines to the I2C bus in addition to the I2C interface. Normally, these will stay tri-stated. When you need to send the magic byte, enable them to send clock and data, then disable them. These won't interfere with I2C, which only drives the bus when transmitting.

Comment: In modern SoCs the I2C port is usually already backed up by GPIO function, so one needs to hijack lines forth and back whenever this specific frame has to be sent, but this is far of violation I2C signal and protocol specifications...

Comment: turning on and off the alternate i2c function may cause unwanted signal excursions. The adi devices I use don't spec what happens if you change the function after initialization.